# Is there a JSON library for C# like C++ Rest SDK web::json::value that can unserialize unknow JSON

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

Checking previous answers (3100), can't find an straight answer for that

**The problem:**

When trying to parse data form a server API, the data has many different layouts depending of the data associated with the resource requested.

Some times the answer is a collection of unstructured data for some entry points and those are the ones the APP need to parse.

The **Json.NET** JSON framework for .NET from ***Newtonsoft*** require a prerequisite class already defined to match *"a previous know structure"* for the serialized JSON to be deserialized.

Apparently is for ***serialize and deserialize any .NET object*** and work with those .NET objects, **but not** *serialize and deserialize JSON in JSON objects*, and work with those objects like with the C++ Rest SDK web::json::value class.

Some requests have structured information and was solved defining .NET objects and deserialized them, but when ask for the extra resource data the answers can be (among many others):

```
  [
    null
  ]
```

or

```
  [
    {
      "item": "value"
    }
  ]
```

or

```
  [
    {
        "item": "value"
    },
    {
        "item2": {}
    },
    {
        "item3": {
            "feature": "string feature",
            "feature2": {
                "object feature": "large object (replaced by string for simplicity)"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "item4": "large object (replaced by string for simplicity too)"
    }
  ]
```

Can anyone know if there is a way (trick, hack) to do this or way to  support generic *JSON objects* that can be use to serialize, deserialize and query, set, modify the JSON objects?

Comment: you can use Newtonsoft to parse a json string in a JObject/JArray without having a predefined C# class

Comment: deserializing and serializing is for converting a format to and from objects,  parsing is for json,  and newtonsoft can parse json and you can query the json without putting it into objects

Comment: modified your question to take out the request for another library as particularly pedantic people will see that  as offtopic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExpandoObject`:

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
```

Comment: An exception was thrown: 
    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
      at (wrapper castclass) System.Object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[] converters)

Comment: What was the json input you provided into it?

Comment: The first one (when no extra information available):

'

    json = "[null]";

'

Comment: Also the other 2 examples and a long live test.

Comment: It work without the _ExpandoObjectConverter_ variable: _**converter**_, just **dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);**.  This create a dynamic _Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer_ base class, or a _null_ object if a "null" JSON is pass.  The array with a null element generates an array container with a null token.